# PSSH command with different arguments to multiple hosts

Tags: bash, scripting, parameter-passing, pssh

I'm trying to write a bash script using PSSH which sends the same command but different arguments depending on the host. The host name and arguments will be pulled from a different file 'list.txt'.

An example of a 'list.txt' file would look like this:

```
10.0.0.1;'hello';'world'
10.0.0.2;'goodbye';'everyone'
10.0.0.3;'thank';'you!'
```

An example of what I currently have (but unfortunately isn't working) is shown below:

```
#!/bin/bash

# grab the list items and make them into a variable to be able to parse
actionList=$(</root/scripts/list.txt)

# parse out host name for pssh
host_name="$( cut -d ';' -sf 1 <<< "$actionList" )";

# parse out the first argument 
argument1="$( cut -d ';' -sf 2 <<< "$actionList" )";

# parse out the second argument
argument2="$( cut -d ';' -sf 3 <<< "$actionList" )";

# pssh command that creates a new file on each server with their respective argument1 and argument2 
pssh -i -AH $host_name -t 300 -O StrictHostKeyChecking=no "$(argument1) ' and ' $(argument2) >> arg1_and_arg2.txt"
```

I'm pretty sure cutting the $actionList variable is not giving me what I want, but what I'm really stuck on is whether that pssh command will run correctly for every item in 'list.txt' after I've parsed out the correct strings from $actionList.

Is there a way to make same command, changing arguments from file work with PSSH? Is there a better program to do this with? If so how? Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

P.S. If I formatted or did anything wrong with this post, I apologize. StackOverflow is usually my last resort so I don't use it often. Again, thanks for any help/advice!

Comment: I don't think `pssh` can do what you want; it is intended to run the *same* command (arguments included) on different hosts.

Comment: Note that expanding a variable creates *literal* quotes (ones that are data), not *syntactic* ones (quotes that are parsed as syntax by bash). Thus, you almost certainly want to leave the `'`s out of your file.

Comment: @chepner I was afraid of that answer.. Happen to know of any other utilities/programs that can help accomplish this?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy thanks for the info! Will change that from now on!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are better off simply using a loop that runs `ssh` for each line of the input file.

```
while IFS=";" read host arg1 arg2; do
    echo "$arg1 and $arg2" | ssh "$host" "cat > arg1_and_arg2.txt" &
done < list.txt
```

Comment: I do already have a way to do this sequentially, but would like to be able to run this command in parallel to be time efficient.

Comment: @FranciscoTapia, see the `&` causing the pipeline running `ssh` to be started in the background. On account of that, this *does* run code in parallel. (The most obvious risk here is that it may be *too* parallel, if you have a longer list of hosts than you can afford to start concurrent processes for, but that's something a little restructuring with `xargs -P` will fix).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Wow, totally missed the '&' !
And yes, I may need to run this command on 400+ hosts so I would need to limit the amount of concurrent processes. I'll most definitely look into this solution more and will update this question with my solution.  Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Honestly, 400 processes isn't *that* many, especially since the amount of work each does locally is minimal. Each process will spend nearly all its time simply sleeping until the remote process completes.

Comment: @chepner this worked for what I needed! Thanks for the help again! Will have to look into the ' xargs ' option Charles pointed out. For now everything is good to go!